# get integet value from a "tf.experimental.numpy.random.randint"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to generate a random integer number using tensorflow. Below code I have found in tensorflow nightly version . How to get integer value from this code. or is there any way to generate random integer in tensorflow

```
tf.experimental.numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=1,dtype=np.int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = tf.experimental.numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=1,dtype=np.int)

a.tolist()
>>> [2]

int(a)
>>> 2

np.array(a)
>>> array([2])

np.array(a)[0]
>>> 2
```

For TF 2.3.0:

```
g1 = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(1)
a = g1.uniform([1], minval=0, maxval=15, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, name=None)

print(a)
>>> tf.Tensor([8], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)

a.numpy()
>>>array([8], dtype=int32)
```

Also, you can use tensor 'a' directly in TF operations, without retrieving its undelaying value.